# OpenSSL: Initializing EVP_PKEY gives symbol error

Tags: c++, openssl, libcrypto

I have a function that takes as parameter an unique_ptr of cctx and **EVP_PKEY_HKDEF_MODE_EXTRACT_ONLY** mode. When I call these two  **init_pkey_ctx** functions from constructor, I get following symbol error.

```
symbol lookup error: libkerf.code.so: undefined symbol: EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_hkdf_mode
```

I have the following piece of code:

```
NCF_SYMBOL_VISIBLE kerf_decryptor():
  cctx(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(), &EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free),
  pctx_extract(EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_HKDF, nullptr), &EVP_PKEY_CTX_free),
  pctx_expand(EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_HKDF, nullptr), &EVP_PKEY_CTX_free)
  {
      if (!cctx || !pctx_expand || !pctx_extract)
        NCF_LOG_ERROR(acu_event_id::sei_cl_mod_code_classify_kerf_fail_decryption, "Initializing the kerf_decryptor: EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new");

    init_pkey_ctx(pctx_extract.get(),EVP_PKEY_HKDEF_MODE_EXTRACT_ONLY);
    init_pkey_ctx(pctx_expand.get(), EVP_PKEY_HKDEF_MODE_EXPAND_ONLY);
  }                                                                                        
                                                                                   
  //initialize pkey(the source of error)                                                                                         
  void init_pkey_ctx(EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx, std::int32_t mode)
  {

  if (EVP_PKEY_derive_init(ctx) <= 0) {
      NCF_LOG_ERROR(acu_event_id::sei_cl_mod_code_classify_kerf_fail_decryption, "EVP_PKEY_derive_init");
     }
  if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_hkdf_mode(ctx, mode) <= 0){
      NCF_LOG_ERROR(acu_event_id::sei_cl_mod_code_classify_kerf_fail_decryption, "EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_hkdf_mode");
     }
  if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_hkdf_md(ctx, EVP_sha256()) <= 0){
      NCF_LOG_ERROR(acu_event_id::sei_cl_mod_code_classify_kerf_fail_decryption, "EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_hkdf_md");
     }
  }                                                               
                                                                
  std::unique_ptr<EVP_CIPHER_CTX, decltype(&EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free)> cctx;
  std::unique_ptr<EVP_PKEY_CTX, decltype(&EVP_PKEY_CTX_free)> pctx_extract;
  std::unique_ptr<EVP_PKEY_CTX, decltype(&EVP_PKEY_CTX_free)> pctx_expand;
```

Comment: Your `libkerf.code.so` is not linked to openssl libraries.

Comment: However, I linked in cmake with make_component(kerf.code.so PRIVATE OpenSSL::OpenSSL)

Comment: When I delete init_pkey_ctx() function, it works